# Why does attempted file redirection break this code?

Tags: c++, linux

This is basically supposed to execute linux shell commands entered by the user and call execvp
For my test function, why is it that when ever a command is entered like '
   ls -l > sample.txt
Not only does the command not execute but the file is not created either.

However if I run the command without the redirection it works fine.

Also after a failed run with a file name attached the shell is completely broken and even a normal command that worked previously will not work.

It also seems as if ls -l will sometimes break the next input command.Then it becomes unable to find ls or any other command.

Edit: After any failed command it will unable to fin any previously working command.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>


void testFunction(int num, char **argv, char **fname)
{
   std::cout << "vvv testFunctionBegin vvv" << std::endl;
   int status;
   int fd;

   if (fork() != 0)
   {
      std::cout << "fork() != 0" << std::endl;
      waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << "fork() == 0" << std::endl;
      /*
      if (isalnum(*fname[0]) || ispunct(*fname[0]))
      {
          std::cout << "File has "<< *fname[0] << std::endl;
          fd = open(fname[0], O_WRONLY, O_APPEND, O_CREAT);
          std::cout << "fd = " << fd << std::endl;
          std::cout << "fname = " << fname[1] << std::endl;
          perror("open");
          dup2(fd, 1);
          close(fd);

      }
      */
      std::cout << "argv[0] = " << *argv[0] << std::endl;
      execvp(argv[0], argv);
   }

}

std::vector<std::string> processString(std::string userInput)
{
   int j = 0;
   std::vector<std::string> subStrs;
   for (int i = 0; i < userInput.size(); i++)
   {
      bool sameSeq = false;
      if (isalnum(userInput[i]) || ispunct(userInput[i]))
      {
         subStrs.resize(subStrs.size() + 1);
         while (isalnum(userInput[i]) || ispunct(userInput[i]))
         {
            subStrs[j].push_back(userInput[i]);
            sameSeq = true;
            //std::cout << "userInput[" << i << "] = " << userInput[i] 
            //          << " --> " << "subStrs[" << j << "] = "
            //          <<  subStrs[j] << std::endl; 
            i++;
         }
         if (sameSeq)
         {
            subStrs[j].push_back('\0');
            j++;   
         }
      }

   }
   return subStrs;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   std::string userInput;
   std::string readySym = "$ ";
   std::vector<std::string> subStrs(1, "");
   std::vector<char*> cmdFlgs;
   std::vector<char*> fileName;

   while (true)
   {  
      std::cout << readySym;
      getline(std::cin, userInput, '\n');

      int j = 0;
      bool fileDirect = false;

      if(!userInput.empty())
      {
         // Put user input into vecotr of strings
         subStrs = processString(userInput);
         int i = 0;
         while ((i < subStrs.size()) && (subStrs[i] != ">") )
         {
            cmdFlgs.push_back(const_cast<char*>(subStrs[i].c_str()));
            i++;
         }

         /*for (int i = 0; i < cmdFlgs.size(); i++)
         {
            std::cout << "cmdFlgs[" << i << "] = " << cmdFlgs[i] << std::endl;
            std::cout << "It is: " << isspace(*cmdFlgs[i]) << std::endl;
         } 
         */
         int j = 0;
         if ( ++i < subStrs.size())
         {
            fileName.push_back(const_cast<char*>(subStrs[i].c_str()));
            std::cout << "fileName[" << i << "] = " << fileName[i] << std::endl;
         }

         testFunction(cmdFlgs.size(), cmdFlgs.data(), fileName.data());     
         fileName.clear(); 
         cmdFlgs.clear(); 
      }

   subStrs.clear();
   subStrs.resize(1);
   }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post so that it includes a [mcve]. The code you showed is not a [mcve].

Comment: Will do when I get chance to.

Answer (score 1):

Your expectation of what execvp and how the shell works is wrong. execvp will execute the program given and pass the remainder of the commands line parameters to the program as arguments.  When you run it on the command line the shell does some work to understand that '>' symbol is not to be passed to the program being called, and is to be interpreted as a redirect.

Comment: THe > never makes it to the command. I will have to post all of the code when I get a second. The fileName var is filled with the desired output file name is the > is types by the user.

Answer (score 0):

If an output redirection operator is not entered, the `fileName` array will be empty.

```
     if ( ++i < subStrs.size())
     {
        fileName.push_back(const_cast<char*>(subStrs[i].c_str()));
```

If this `if` branch is not taken, `fileName` will remain a completely empty vector. P.S.: this `const_cast` made my eyes bleed.

```
testFunction(cmdFlgs.size(), cmdFlgs.data(), fileName.data());
```

fileName.data() will be a null pointer in this case.

Your question was the fact that with the commented portion in place, your code does not work.

```
if (isalnum(*fname[0]) || ispunct(*fname[0]))
```

Since the `fname` parameter is a null pointer, you will have a null pointer dereference here.

Additionally, this code is suffering from a severe case of C-itis. This is a condition that mostly afflicts C++ code that thinks it's not C++ code, but rather C code.

For example:

```
subStrs[j].push_back('\0');
```

This is completely unnecessary. `std::string` automatically takes care of details like always appending a \0 at the end of the string for you. This is no longer C, this is C++. And, in C++, we don't deal with silliness like appending `\0`s to strings. That's what `std::string` is for.

```
     if (sameSeq)
     {
        subStrs[j].push_back('\0');
        j++;   
     }
```

Same thing. None of this is needed. Additionally, here's a homework assignment for you. Try to figure out why `sameSeq` will always be `true` here. No exceptions (free clue, look at the immediately preceding `if` and `while` conditions). Just more unneeded code to remove, here.

PS. All of the above was determined quickly with a help of a debugger, namely `gdb`, that is the same `gdb` that's on your linux box. That's another thing you should look into: learning how to use `gdb`.

Comment: Also, additionally, because you explicitly append a trailing \0 to the string, instead of the std::string containing ">", the std::string ends up containing ">\0". Subsequently, the comparison subStrs[i] != ">" will FAIL, because subStrs[i] will contain two characters, > and \0. Another victim of C-itis.

Comment: I am not a very good programmer, I wouldn't try to convince anyone otherwise. I actually learned c++ first and have never learned C. I did it like that because I didn't know how else to get it into the format requires for execvp(..).